# NHibernate QueryOver - Search across 2 tables, returning some aggregate data, perfoming sort/skip/take on sqlserver side

Tags: nhibernate, c#-4.0, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following entities (that map directly to DB tables):

```
public class SurveyQuestion
{
public int SurveyQuestionID { get; set; }
public string QuestionText { get; set; }
public DateTime QuestionDate { get; set; }
public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
public int AnswerID { get; set; }
public int SurveyQuestionID { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to execute a query that returns the following (expressed as a class here for clarity and because I have the class to copy/paste from one of my many failed attempts):

```
public class SurveySearchItem
{
public int SurveyQuestionID { get; set; }
public string QuestionText { get; set; }
public int AnswerCount { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like for this query to filter on date, order by the count, skip X rows, and take X rows, all on the sql server side.  I'm trying to avoid writing a proc or just having the sql for this inline, as everywhere else I've been able to do everything I need solely using nhibernate's queryover or criteria stuff.

I've googled up many promising links (most here on SO) and tried many different things, but I can't seem to find a way to make this happen.  If it isn't a thing that can be done without writing the sql myself (or possibly making a search view with an entity mapped to it; I've considered that, too) I'm ok with that.  It just seems like there should be a way to do this with QueryOver or something and that I'm probably just too much of a noob to figure it out.

Comment: have you tried Session.Query<SurveyQuestion>().Where(s => s.QuestionDate > someDate).Select(s => new SurveySearchItem { SurveyQuestionID = s.SurveyQuestionID, QuestionText = s.QuestionText, AnswerCount = s.Answers.Count()).OrderBy(s => s.AnswerCount).Skip(pageSize * pageIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList() ?

Comment: @Vasea won't work since this is IQueryable and not ienumerable.

Comment: @Firo I don't understand, this query works well on current 3.3 NHibernate LINQ provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with a view in the DB and creating a class mapped to it via nhibernate (and then forgetting I'd posted this question for about 6 months).  That was the absolute simplest solution and since then I've had to do the same in similar scenarios on other projects.  One could argue that the proc or inline sql route may have been a better choice, but the view method kept it more consistent with all the other code (in that it looks like just another entity mapped to just another table).